Can I update one index in a 2d texture array while rendering with another index?
Let's say I have a 2d texture array with two indices, 0 and 1. If I upload an image to index 0 and render with it, can I upload another image to index 1 while the render is ongoing?

OpenGL, being a largely synchronous API, allows this. The real question is whether doing this will cause the GPU to stall, waiting for rendering to complete before issuing the copy operation. OpenGL doesn't give us an answer for this.
I would not expect that these two operations would happen asynchronously. It may be permitted on some, or even lots of, hardware, but the API can't tell us that this will be the case.

Do you know if this applies to Vulkan? I tried looking through the spec, but couldn't find anything. I'm guessing I just missed it due to how thorough the spec is.

In Vulkan, all synchronization is handled manually. In Vulkan, images have "subresources" in them, and each "subresource" can be treated distinctly from others. They can have their own image layouts, for example. Different array layers of the same mipmap are different subresources, so they can have different image layouts. So it is possible to have one layer in a copy-destination layout while the other is in the shader-read layout. Also, subresources can be assigned exclusive access by queue families individually, so one layer can be transferred to while the other is used.
